# Unity3d drawing with whitespaces

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I drew lines using LineRenderer. Game is 2d. What I want now is to create whitespace in line with the line on the gameobject with collider.

Here is the code I use for drawing and adding collider to line. What I want is not to draw a line on gameobjects, like circles(with CircleCollider2D) or squares(with BoxCollider2D). I want to have two different LineRenderers: one is finishing on collider, second is starting on it. [What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuEB2.png) That square does not hide the line. There is not a line where the square is.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer line;
    private bool isMousePressed;
    public bool isLeftMousePressed = false;

    public List<Vector3> pointsList;

    private Vector3 mousePos;
    public float width = 0.05f;

    // Structure for line points
    struct myLine
    {
        public Vector3 StartPoint;
        public Vector3 EndPoint;
    };
    //    -----------------------------------    
    void Awake()
    {
        // Create line renderer component and set its property
        line = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.material = (Material)Resources.Load("Materials/LineMat");

        line.startWidth = width;
        line.endWidth = width;

        line.useWorldSpace = true;
        isMousePressed = false;
        pointsList = new List<Vector3>();

    }
    //    -----------------------------------    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
           isLeftMousePressed = true;
        }

        if (isLeftMousePressed||Game.currentLevel == 0) return;

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            isMousePressed = true; 
        }

        // Drawing line when mouse is moving(pressed)
        if (isMousePressed)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                isMousePressed = false;

                GameObject curve = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Curve"), transform.parent);
                curve.GetComponent<DrawLine>().width = width;

                if (line.GetPosition(line.positionCount - 1).z == 1) Destroy(gameObject);
                else enabled = false;
            }

            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            mousePos.z = 0;

            if (!pointsList.Contains(mousePos))
            {
                pointsList.Add(mousePos);
                line.positionCount = pointsList.Count;
                line.SetPosition(pointsList.Count - 1, (Vector3)pointsList[pointsList.Count - 1]);

                try
                {
                    AddColliderToLine(line, (Vector3)pointsList[pointsList.Count - 2], (Vector3)pointsList[pointsList.Count - 1]);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }   
        }
    }

    //    -----------------------------------    
    //    Following method checks whether given two points are same or not
    //    -----------------------------------    
    private bool checkPoints(Vector3 pointA, Vector3 pointB)
    {
        return (pointA.x == pointB.x && pointA.y == pointB.y);
    }

    private void AddColliderToLine(LineRenderer line, Vector3 startPoint, Vector3 endPoint)
    {
        //create the collider for the line
        GameObject lcObject = new GameObject("LineCollider");
        BoxCollider2D lineCollider = lcObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

        lcObject.layer = 2; // ignore raycast

        //set the collider as a child of your line
        lineCollider.transform.parent = line.transform;
        // get width of collider from line 
        float lineWidth = line.endWidth;
        // get the length of the line using the Distance method
        float lineLength = Vector3.Distance(startPoint, endPoint);
        // size of collider is set where X is length of line, Y is width of line
        //z will be how far the collider reaches to the sky
        lineCollider.size = new Vector3(lineLength, lineWidth);
        // get the midPoint
        Vector3 midPoint = (startPoint + endPoint) / 2;

        // move the created collider to the midPoint
        lineCollider.transform.position = midPoint;


        //heres the beef of the function, Mathf.Atan2 wants the slope, be careful however because it wants it in a weird form
        //it will divide for you so just plug in your (y2-y1),(x2,x1)
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2((endPoint.y - startPoint.y), (endPoint.x - startPoint.x));

        // angle now holds our answer but it's in radians, we want degrees
        // Mathf.Rad2Deg is just a constant equal to 57.2958 that we multiply by to change radians to degrees
        angle *= Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        //were interested in the inverse so multiply by -1
        //angle *= -1;
        // now apply the rotation to the collider's transform, carful where you put the angle variable
        // in 3d space you don't wan't to rotate on your y axis
        lineCollider.transform.Rotate(0, 0, angle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more o information, like a snippet of your code, a drawing or picture of the effect you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make dotted line, you can see [2D Dotted LineRenderer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1041971/2d-dotted-linerenderer.html)

And add the collider on the part you want

```
 gameObject.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
```

**Edit:**

Check if mouse is inside the square by raycast

```
if (isMousePressed)
{
    var stopDrawing = false;  
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        if(hit.transform.tag == "square" || hit.transform.tag == "circle") {
            stopDrawing  = true;
        }
    }
    if(stopDrawing) 
    {
        // Stop current line, prepare a new List<Vector3> for next line
    }
    else{
        // Continue draw current line
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. I wrote more details. Thank you for answer!

Comment: Tnx. But I still have one problem. If I draw with high speed, the curve (line) will be finished before it touched the object. Because the last point of line is on square and we do not draw this point and the line between last and previous point. Because update function works too rarely. So I need to add point where the line touces the border of the square

Comment: You're right. We should involve the last point to extend the curve.[Collision.contact](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html) may help you to calculate the contact point